# Swift: Accessing JSON received by post request

Tags: ios, json, swift, http, post

```
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: postRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "NoData")
            return
        }
        let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
        self.submitView.text = jsonString
    }
    task.resume()
```

I'm trying to access the return value of this post request. I set a breakpoint and saw that jsonString does get the correct value. However, which I try to set self.submitView.text to anything, I get this error:

```
2017-06-21 14:20:16.062815-0400 Button[958:197756] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191c82ff8 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001906e4538 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191c82f28 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000192874338 <redacted> + 128
    4   Foundation                          0x00000001926bc9f8 <redacted> + 36
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000197daf76c <redacted> + 816
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000197dbb668 <redacted> + 1740
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000197dbaf84 <redacted> + 828
    8   UIKit                               0x0000000197df90f4 <redacted> + 256
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000197df1818 <redacted> + 116
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001987ec308 <redacted> + 48
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000197e5d880 <redacted> + 280
    12  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197cdb238 <redacted> + 7012
    13  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197cdc0c8 <redacted> + 52
    14  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d0eb70 <redacted> + 48
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000197e5d85c <redacted> + 244
    16  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197ce0214 <redacted> + 2172
    17  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d0b058 <redacted> + 240
    18  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d2f474 <redacted> + 160
    19  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d2ebb4 <redacted> + 92
    20  UIKit                               0x0000000197e60500 <redacted> + 252
    21  UIKit                               0x0000000197e603e4 <redacted> + 196
    22  Button                              0x0000000100061e24 _TFFC6Button14ViewController12submitTappedFT_T_U_FTGSqV10Foundation4Data_GSqCSo11URLResponse_GSqPs5Error___T_ + 784
    23  Button                              0x0000000100062468 _TTRXFo_oGSqV10Foundation4Data_oGSqCSo11URLResponse_oGSqPs5Error____XFdCb_dGSqCSo6NSData_dGSqS1__dGSqCSo7NSError___ + 224
    24  CFNetwork                           0x000000019228c34c <redacted> + 32
    25  CFNetwork                           0x00000001922a4048 <redacted> + 148
    26  Foundation                          0x0000000192751814 <redacted> + 16
    27  Foundation                          0x0000000192696770 <redacted> + 96
    28  Foundation                          0x0000000192686b28 <redacted> + 612
    29  Foundation                          0x0000000192753bb0 <redacted> + 228
    30  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a6da10 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    31  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a7b2e8 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1140
    32  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a71634 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 852
    33  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a7d630 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
    34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a7d39c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 140
    35  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190d43100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
    36  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190d42cac start_wqthread + 4
)
2017-06-21 14:20:16.085280-0400 Button[958:197756] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread after the engine was accessed from the main thread. This can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.
 Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191c82ff8 <redacted> + 148
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001906e4538 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000191c82f28 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000192874338 <redacted> + 128
    4   Foundation                          0x00000001926bc9f8 <redacted> + 36
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000197eb18e0 <redacted> + 564
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000197db0138 <redacted> + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000197daf8d0 <redacted> + 120
    8   Foundation                          0x00000001926bca7c <redacted> + 168
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000197daf76c <redacted> + 816
    10  UIKit                               0x0000000197dbb668 <redacted> + 1740
    11  UIKit                               0x0000000197dbaf84 <redacted> + 828
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000197df90f4 <redacted> + 256
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000197df1818 <redacted> + 116
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001987ec308 <redacted> + 48
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000197e5d880 <redacted> + 280
    16  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197cdb238 <redacted> + 7012
    17  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197cdc0c8 <redacted> + 52
    18  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d0eb70 <redacted> + 48
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000197e5d85c <redacted> + 244
    20  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197ce0214 <redacted> + 2172
    21  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d0b058 <redacted> + 240
    22  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d2f474 <redacted> + 160
    23  UIFoundation                        0x0000000197d2ebb4 <redacted> + 92
    24  UIKit                               0x0000000197e60500 <redacted> + 252
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000197e603e4 <redacted> + 196
    26  Button                              0x0000000100061e24 _TFFC6Button14ViewController12submitTappedFT_T_U_FTGSqV10Foundation4Data_GSqCSo11URLResponse_GSqPs5Error___T_ + 784
    27  Button                              0x0000000100062468 _TTRXFo_oGSqV10Foundation4Data_oGSqCSo11URLResponse_oGSqPs5Error____XFdCb_dGSqCSo6NSData_dGSqS1__dGSqCSo7NSError___ + 224
    28  CFNetwork                           0x000000019228c34c <redacted> + 32
    29  CFNetwork                           0x00000001922a4048 <redacted> + 148
    30  Foundation                          0x0000000192751814 <redacted> + 16
    31  Foundation                          0x0000000192696770 <redacted> + 96
    32  Foundation                          0x0000000192686b28 <redacted> + 612
    33  Foundation                          0x0000000192753bb0 <redacted> + 228
    34  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a6da10 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    35  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a7b2e8 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 1140
    36  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a71634 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 852
    37  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a7d630 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 552
    38  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100a7d39c _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 140
    39  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190d43100 _pthread_wqthread + 1096
    40  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000190d42cac start_wqthread + 4
)
2017-06-21 14:20:16.088842-0400 Button[958:197756] *** Assertion failure in void _UIPerformResizeOfTextViewForTextContainer(NSLayoutManager *, UIView<NSTextContainerView> *, NSTextContainer *, NSUInteger)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIFoundation/UIFoundation-491.7/UIFoundation/TextSystem/NSLayoutManager_Private.m:1577
2017-06-21 14:20:16.089727-0400 Button[958:197756] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Only run on the main thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x191c82fe0 0x1906e4538 0x191c82eb4 0x19271a78c 0x197cd93f8 0x197cd90d8 0x197d07e88 0x197d0b188 0x197d2f474 0x197d2ebb4 0x197e60500 0x197e603e4 0x100061e24 0x100062468 0x19228c34c 0x1922a4048 0x192751814 0x192696770 0x192686b28 0x192753bb0 0x100a6da10 0x100a7b2e8 0x100a71634 0x100a7d630 0x100a7d39c 0x190d43100 0x190d42cac)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

It seems like I can't assign self.submitView.text to anything inside the scope of "task". Any ideas why?

Edit:
Here is what the server returns upon sending a request.

`"{\"raw\":\"schedule for John in New York on Monday\",\"location\":\"New York\",\"date\":\"Mon, June 26\",\"name\":\"john\",\"errorResponse\":null,\"stripTest\":\"for John in new york on Monday\"}"`

This is what my code looks like:

`do {
                let info = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.submitView.text = info?["name"] as! String
                }
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.submitView.text = "ERROR"
                }
            }`

"ERROR" is no longer printing, but "info" seems to have 0 key/value pairs, thus nothing prints.

UPDATE:

`print(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []))` prints "nil"

The latter prints:

```
Optional("\"{\\\"raw\\\":\\\"Schedule for John in New York on Monday\\\",\\\"location\\\":\\\"new york\\\",\\\"date\\\":\\\"6/26/2017 12:00:00 AM\\\",\\\"name\\\":\\\"john\\\",\\\"errorResponse\\\":null,\\\"stripTest\\\":\\\" for john in new york on monday \\\"}\"")
```

This isn't what prints when I assign it to a text view in the UI.. is it converting the escape sequences to literal characters?

Comment: Provide please json example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the text property of the UITextField on a background thread.

You need to ensure that all UI work is done on the main thread, You can do this using [DispatchQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue)...

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.submitView.text = jsonString
}
```

**Update:**

The data is literally the data that was sent over the network, you will need to convert and deserialise it.

You can do this using the [JSON Serialisation class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization) like so:

```
// I create some dummy JSON string for example purposes
let data = "{ \"name\": \"John Smith\"}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    print(jsonObject["name"] as! String)
}
```

This tries to convert the data into a JSON object, which in Swift is usually cast to a dictionary object.

There are loads of resources on networking with Swift available. One I highly recommend would be [iOS Networking with Swift](https://www.udacity.com/course/ios-networking-with-swift--ud421) this would take a fair bit of time to go through and learn so here is something that is alot quicker to get through [Working with JSON in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=37)

UPDATE

This code works for me:

```
let data = "{\"raw\":\"schedule for John in New York on Monday\",\"location\":\"New York\",\"date\":\"Mon, June 26\",\"name\":\"john\",\"errorResponse\":null,\"stripTest\":\"for John in new york on Monday\"}".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!

if let jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] {
    print(jsonObject)
    print(jsonObject["name"] as! String)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. By the way, could you possibly explain to me what "data" is? XCODE tells me it's of type "Data". The return type should be a JSON and now I'm trying to deserialize this into an object, but I'm struggling with types.

Comment: Hey thanks for the detailed answer! Unfortunately, I've already tried methods like that without success (I tried your solution verbatim to double check).

`do {
                let info = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String : Any]
            } catch {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.submitView.text = "ERROR"
                }
            }`

This results in "ERROR" being printed, meaning JSONSerialization is throwing an exception.

Comment: please show the JSON that you have in your Question above

Comment: I've added the JSON to the bottom of my original post.

Comment: using the same JSON as above?

Comment: I narrowed down the problem. I tried explicitly typing out the JSON and using that instead of what the server returns, and it works. For some reason, what the server returns is slightly different, even though when I print it they are identical. So I'm assuming "data" is not what I think it is?

Comment: check your response from the server with jsonlint.com and ensure that you are getting valid JSON back

Comment: jsonlint.com says it's valid. Is the return value directly being stored inside "data"? Is it possible that the request isn't expecting a JSON so it's somehow deleting some characters or messing up formatting?

Comment: try `print(try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []))` and see what that gives. you currently cast to [String:AnyObject] but if your server returns an array that could be different. Your response will receive the body of the response as Data which contains your jsonString. if nothing comes out of that print statement, try `String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)` (I typed that from memory rather than checking in xcode so check it) and print that. see what you get

Comment: I've updated the original post because I don't know how to format comments.

Comment: It looks like its double escaped, too many backslahes for JSON. It  appears to be adding an extra backslash and then escaping that

Comment: I'm going to see if there's a way to avoid the extra backslashes and the "Optional" part. If not, I'll just manually delete it. Thanks for all the help!